# What's wrong with this Quick Sort program?

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I am sort of a beginner at coding and this is my C program for quick sort. Something seems to be wrong though because for the array `{6,76,32,18,9,90,43,45,3,1}` the output comes out as `{1,3,6,9,18,32,45,43,76,90}`. I don't know why `45` is coming before `43`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int list[], int l, int r) {
    int pi = l;
    int too_big = l + 1;
    int too_small = r;

    while (too_big < too_small) {
        while (list[too_big] <= list[pi] && too_big < r)
            too_big++;
        while (list[too_small] > list[pi] && too_small > l)
            too_small--;
        if (too_big < too_small)
            swap(&list[too_big], &list[too_small]);
    }
    swap(&list[pi], &list[too_small]);

    return too_small;
}

void qsort(int list[], int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int pi = partition(list, l, r);
        qsort(list, l, pi - 1);
        qsort(list, pi + 1, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should do yourself a favor and format your code properly.

Comment: The error occurs when you partition an array of two elements: You won't enter the `while` loop and then by swapping the pivot back in unconditionally "miscorrect" the order. Either ckeck before swapping or force enetring the `while` loop by starting with `too_big = l;`.

Answer (score 5):

You can debug your function by printing the partitioned array before returning from `partition`. For your example, you get:

```
  3  1  6 18  9 90 43 45 32 76
       ^^
  1  3  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    ^^
  .  .  .  9 18 90 43 45 32 76
             ^^
  .  .  .  .  . 76 43 45 32 90
                            ^^
  .  .  .  .  . 32 43 45 76  .
                         ^^
  .  .  .  .  . 32 43 45  .  .
                ^^
  .  .  .  .  .  . 45 43  .  .
                      ^^
```

(`^^` marks the pivot.) You'll see that `45` and `43` are swapped, but they shouldn't, because they are already in order.

The faulty swap happens when you swap the pivot into place unconditionally at the end and when you are partitioning an array of two elements. In that case, the main loop isn't entered and you may have `too_small` sitting on an element that doesn't belong to the left partition.

Check whether swapping disturbs the partition before swapping.

Comment: Thank you, I've understood it now. It was a pretty small mistake but I couldn't point it out. Thanks a lot for explaining it so well.